# Parameters determining the batch processing speed

Tags: batch

Suppose I have batch class which runs an operation on all the leads present. If I have 1 million records and my batch class executes 2000 records at a time, this means I have 500 batches. What are the parameters that define the speed at which these batches execute?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter used for batch processing speed is the number of records in an object / table that it is being read from, the bytes size of the row, the total bytes of the table/object data  and the number of connection pools that are trying to access the object/table.